# How to load xml cascade file in openCV 2.3.1

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I try bulid face detect applicatyion on Visual Studio 2010 using C++ and OpenCV 2.3.1 library
So, I declaration String type and initialize:

> String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

Next, I create a object of class CascadeClassifier:

> CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

And I load cascade:

> if( !face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

The project bulid and debugging without problem, but when I run application and application try load cascade program crash!

And I see this communication:
The program '[1288] OpenCV2.0.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: In your case, I suggest you post the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your issue. We can't help if we don't know what your program is trying to accomplish, the best way to understand, is by reviewing the code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `CascadeClassifier` and `FileStorage`.

For example if you try this:

```
FileStorage fs(xml_fname, FileStorage::READ);
if (!fs.isOpened())
{
    cout<<"can not read xml"<<endl;
}
```

Probably, it won't work.

In my case, I passed in VC++ from Debugging mode to Release mode, specified `.lib` files without `d` at the end (e.g. `opencv_core231.lib`) and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case(OSX 10.9), I input the whole path instead of simply "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", like "/Users/xxx/Desktop/opencv-2.4.7/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml". Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case (win7 64, VS 10 express), changing file permissions for xml files solved the problem,
I added Everyone with full controll, and it worked.